# After set Up locally project of react js some error occur like this

Tags: reactjs

This error occurs after setting up local CRA project:

unova@0.1.0 start /home/abc/Desktop/aman/esp/project

> react-scripts start

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../scripts/start'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/abc/Desktop/aman/esp/project/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts:35:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! unova@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the unova@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abc/.npm/_logs/2020-01-15T06_39_05_439Z-debug.log
```

Comment: which version are you using react-scripts ,let me know

Comment: react-scripts - v0.9.5